# Show all tables with a summary description in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, metadata

I am loading a very big testing database into MYSQL (I have a script running to load all the tables). I think the loading process is going to take a few days so I am trying to determine which tables have been completely loaded and also make sure every tuple is correctly stored. I have many tables so I do not want to do a count for each table one by one; I was wondering if there is a function to display all the tables in my database with a summary of the information about them (ie number of rows). So far,I have found the function SHOW TABLES but this does not show any information about the tables. 
Please let me know if there is a way to obtain this information without having to run queries for every table.
Thanks

Comment: you can poke around in the `information_schema` meta-db

Comment: You could use the command `DESCRIBE` table.